# ADO.NET Entity Framework better than the method I am using?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have read a bit about ADO.NET Entity Framework, but there is some things I am missing.  Right now (not using EF, not sure what this technique is called, just ADO.NET?) we store all procedures in the database, that way if we have to change anything we have to just go into the db and change a query, pretty easy (other than the fact I have 100s of queries).

If I am correct with EF, I can query easier (no joins, shorter queries) but everything is saved in the Entity Data Model.  So if I needed to change a query I would have to launch VS go in, find the location and change the query (which I guess would be linq-to-sql or Entity SQL to perform the query)

I just need some clarification about EF, and Entity SQL vs Linq-to-SQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using EF you can use several types of data accessing:

- Enity SQL - it is syntax similar to common SQL but queries are directly in code or entity model. If you want to change query you must rebuild and redeploy application.
- Linq-to-entities - Linq queries on top of entity model. Again if you want to change query you must rebuild and redeploy application.
- Executing stored procedures imported to model (also known as function import) - this is just sotred procedure exposed on your `ObjectContext` as .NET function. EF will handle parameters and result mapping.
- Executing direct SQL by `ExecuteStoreQuery` or `ExecuteStoreCommand` (only EFv4). Here you can call any SQL including stored procedures.

So with EF you have both your current approach plus EF itself. Moreover calling native SQL through EF has some advantages like automatic mapping to prepared classes.

Anyway what you describe is quite uncommon situation. In many companies modifying something in DB requires same process as modifying application (or even more complicated) so you can't simply go and modify stored procedure in production.

Comment: So basically using EF(which is process of getting the database model into VS) gives me more options instead of my one way of data accessing. And keeps the C# programmer separate from the database developer (if that was the case)

Comment: @Spooks: Yes both statements are somehow true but if you really want to use EF effectively you must understand your database server as well.

Comment: I see you did not mention linq-to-sql guessing that is not used for this?

Comment: @Spooks: Linq-to-sql is separate technology (deprecated by MS). EF has bigger feature set.